# minimizing mutual information vs. maximizing negentropy

Tags: machine-learning, information-theory, independence, entropy

I'm reading about independent component analysis (ICA) where the goal is to find an unmixing matrix to maximize independence in latent, linearly mixed sources.

The paper I'm reading (Hyvarinen) says that mutual information is a natural benchmark for this because it is the information-theoretic measure of independence of random variables. It goes on to say that mutual information can be expressed using the concept of negentropy so that maximizing negentropy is roughly equivalent to minimizing mutual information. This is where I'm getting lost.

Terms in paper:

$$\textbf{differential Entropy:  }H(\textbf y) = - \int f(\textbf y) \log f(\textbf y) d \textbf y $$
$$\text{with random vector } \textbf y=(y_1,...,y_n)^T \text{ and density } f(.) $$
$$\textbf{negentropy:  } J(\textbf y ) = H(\textbf y_{gauss} ) - H(\textbf y )$$
$$\text{Property: negentropy is invariant for linear transforms}$$
$$\text{mutual information can be expressed in terms of negentropy:}$$
$$\textbf{mutual information:  } I(\textbf y) = J(\textbf y) - \sum_i J(y_i) \ \ \text{ (5)}$$

It goes on to say that,

> "Because negentropy is invariant for invertible linear
>   transformations, it is now obvious from (5) that finding an invertible
>   transformation $\bf W$ that minimizes the mutual information is
>   roughly equivalent to *finding directions in which the negentropy is
>   maximized.*"

I don't know if this is because I have not studied information theory at all, but this is not obvious to me. Would someone please attempt to give me an intuitive explanation for why this property of negentropy results in the above statement?

Comment: Any chance you have a link to the paper?

Comment: Sure, the quote I'm referring to is on page 3: https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/ahyvarin/papers/TNN99new.pdf

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand through the illustration and explanation on this page: http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/ica/node5.html

Comment: I thought I was the only one here into this stuff. I am trying to understand Polychorics myself.

Comment: I have to expand a 5min high-level school presentation I did on ICA into a 60min presentation, so trying to fill the gaps in my knowledge ;)

Comment: Good luck, I'll see if I can understand the links so I can suggest something useful. good luck with it :).